# How do I round off both positive and negative numbers using one query in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server

```
left(cast(round(s.test, 0) * 100, 3 as varchar(36)), 5) + '%'
```

This displays the results I want, but when it is a negative number like -0.005036 it does not display to 3 decimal places; instead, it displays -0.54.

Comment: The above seems to be missing a parenthesis somewhere.  Do you mean `left(cast(round(@stest * 100, 3) as varchar(36)), 5) + '%' `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL server?
Are you sure you don't just want `FORMAT(s.test, 'P3')`?
FORMAT should work with 2014 and later.  That's probably the best way to do text formatting within SQL.  More documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

> For a full explanation of these formatting patterns, consult the .NET
> Framework documentation on string formatting in general, custom date
> and time formats, and custom number formats. A good starting point is
> the topic, "[Formatting Types](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=211776)."

Comment: left(cast(round(nullif(s.test, 0) * 100, 3 as varchar(36)), 5) + '%'

Comment: sql server 2018. i want to round both positive and negative numbers from one select in query

Comment: How do i format? can you show me an alternative way

Comment: Try adding the `FORMAT(s.test, 'P3')` to your `SELECT` - 'P' means "percent" (which already does the multiplication by 100), and "3" is the number of decimal places you want.